# Converting character vectors of times with different time zones into UTC in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a vector of character values, some of which are in EST and others are in EDT:

```
c("2/28/19 10:09:56 PM EST", "2/28/19 10:46:57 PM EST", "3/13/19 6:41:18 PM EDT", 
"3/13/19 7:05:19 PM EDT", "3/13/19 7:37:50 PM EDT", "3/13/19 7:58:33 PM EDT"
)
```

How'd I convert these character values into a Date object with UTC timezone? I know that if I just had one timezone, like EST, I'd have done:

`with_tz(mdy_hms(date, tz = "EST"), "UTC")`

However, I have EST and EDT mixed together, so don't know how I'd account for that in `lubridate`

Thanks

Comment: Does `mdy_hms(date, tz = "America/New_York")` do what you want?

Comment: Does that convert the character values into UTC?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it looks like it ignores the character timezones and just looks at the time date / time. I.e., if you run `date <- gsub(" E.T", "", date)` and then run the same code it will return the same results. If you have more than eastern time, definitely update the question :)